# Topology of $U(n,n)/U(n) \times U(n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, compactness

I'm wondering about the topological properties of non-compact spaces.

Suppose I have the symmetric space $$\frac{U(n,n)}{ U(n) \times U(n)}$$

where $U(n,n)$ is the pseudo-unitary group and $U(n)$ is the unitary group. As Moishe pointed out, this is diffeomorphic to Euclidean space, and so is topologically trivial.

But now if we impose an additional constraint on the space: $U(s) = U^*(-s)$ where $s$ parametrizes the space and $s \in T^1$ i.e., is periodic, can this space be made non-trivial?

Comment: Some noise: the $U(n)\times U(n)$ is not a _normal_ (conjugation invariant) subgroup of the (not "pseudo", but simply "indefinite signature") unitary group $U(n,n)$, so asking for a subgroup of the quotient doesn't quite make sense, since that quotient is not itself a group. So, then, what really did you want in this situation? Probably something meaningful, but not accurately described by what you literally said?

Comment: This quotient is not a group, what do you mean by a subgroup of it?

Comment: I'm trying to understand if non-compact spaces can have any non-trivial topology associated with them. So I think that instead of "group" I should have said Riemannian symmetric space where that is defined as  a "Riemannian manifold M, such that the
Riemann curvature tensor is covariantly constant, so that ‘the geometry is the same everywhere" See: http://www.thp.uni-koeln.de/zirn/011_Website_Martin_Zirnbauer/4_Publications/PDF_publications/08SuperReview.pdf

Comment: @Aegon: OK, then what do you mean by a "maximally compact subgroup" of a symmetric space? Do you mean "maximal compact subgroup of its isometry group"? Then you already know the answer, $U(n)\times U(n)$ (up to some finite index extension). As for the symmetric space itself, it is diffeomorphic to a Euclidean space. What else do you want to know?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you for that answer, I didn't know it was diffeomorphic to Euclidean space - do you have a reference for that by chance? I have two more questions about this (I'm not well versed in the field of classifying spaces) - If I have $U \in U(n,n)/U(n)\times U(n)$ but if this space has an additional constraint $U(k) = U^*(-k)$ (where $k$ is some parameter, e.g. momentum, that the space is parametrized by), is the space still topologically trivial? And the second, simpler question is, if $GL(n,R)/O(n)$ is also simply connected, thereby trivial. Thank you!

Comment: @MoisheCohen I managed to answer my second question - $GL(n,R)/O(n)$ is homeomorphic to the vector space of all symmetric matrices, which is contractible. However, my first question still remains - in general, if I have a non-compact symmetric space but it is supplemented by some constraint, could it have some non-trivial topology? I'm specifically interested in the case I described above, but even a general argument as to why it couldn't happen would be great